# created producer using rust-rdkafka, but messages cannot be retrieved by kafka consumer in CLI

Tags: rust, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I created the following producer using rust -

```
use rdkafka::config::ClientConfig;
use rdkafka::producer::{BaseProducer, BaseRecord, Producer};
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() 
{
    println!("starting ... ");

    let producer: BaseProducer = ClientConfig::new()
        .set("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .create()
        .expect("invalid producer config");
    
    producer
        .send(
            BaseRecord::to("destination_topic")
            .payload("this is the payload")
            .key("this is the key"),
        ).expect("Failed to enque");
    
    for _ in 0..10
    {
        producer.poll(Duration::from_millis(100));
    }

    producer.flush(Duration::from_secs(1));
}
```

With the .toml file as follows -

```
[package]
name = "kafka-demo-3"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html || rdkafka = "^0.8.1"

[dependencies]

rdkafka = "0.25"

serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
rand = "0.8.3"
```

After writing this code I then -

1. Started zookeeper

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

2. Started kafka broker service

```
$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

3. Ran the above rust producer code
4. Then I tried to consume the messege sent by the producer

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic rust --from-beginning
```

However on doing so I am getting the following message -

```
[2022-05-04 14:19:31,874] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=console-consumer-46832] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {rust=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
^CProcessed a total of 0 messages
```

Not sure whats going wrong

Comment: `BaseRecord::to("destination_topic")`... So why are you expecting data in `--topic rust`?

Comment: Hi yes, that was the mistake. I changed the topic name, but forgot to do it everywhere. I removed the hardcoding now, so shouldn't make this error in the future.

Comment: Did this fix the problem? If not please [edit] your question

Comment: Yes this fixed the problem

Comment: Since this was just a simple typo, feel free to delete the question or provide your full solution below.